# Using Visual Studio Code as alternative for Arduino IDE - Setting register bit fails

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

### Update #1

The code is working now.

> Try putting those four assignments (TCCR1 to TIMSK1) inside a routine, and call it from setup. It's strange to see them treated as global variables; they aren't really. – aMike

You were right. After putting it in a routine I am able to verify and upload the code in VS Code. The result is as expected.

[image]

After the code works now I tried to improve the style of the code, so I did a little research how to make it easier to read. So it looks a bit different now.

> Not that this has anything to do with your problem, but you probably don't want the semicolon in #define PRESCALE_OFFSET 3035; Also, like aMike said.

Thanks for the advice.

Although it works, VS Code still marks the relevant position as not defined as lurker mentioned. But that is how I have to do as far as I know. For example: [Arduino - Port Manipulation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation)

[image]

Thanks for your replies!

**CODE Main.ino**

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*---------------------------------Includes---------------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "init.h"

/****************************************************************************/
/*-------------------------Function Implementations-------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

void setup()
{
  EnableInterrupts();
  InitPeripherals();
}

void loop()
{
  ;
}
```

**CODE init.h**

```
/*---------------------------------Includes---------------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H

/****************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------Function Prototypes---------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

void InitPeripherals(void);
void EnableInterrupts(void);
void InitSensors(void);
void InitTimer(void);

#endif
```

**CODE init.cpp**

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*---------------------------------Includes---------------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

#include "init.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

/****************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------Macros----------------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

#define PRESCALE_OFFSET 3035

/****************************************************************************/
/*-----------------------------Global Variables-----------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/



/****************************************************************************/
/*-------------------------Function Implementations-------------------------*/
/****************************************************************************/

void EnableInterrupts(void)
{
  TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1); //enable interrupts on timer2 (16bit timer)
}

void InitSensors(void)
{
  ;
}

void InitTimer(void)
{
  TCCR1A = 0; //WGM10 WGM11 normal mode for 16bit timer
  TCCR1B = 0; //WGM12 WGM13 normal mode for 16bit timer
  TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12); //prescaler set to 256
}

void InitPeripherals(void)
{
  EnableInterrupts();
  InitSensors();
  InitTimer();
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

/* Declare the Timer Interrupt Function*/
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)
{
  TCNT1 = PRESCALE_OFFSET; //let the timer start at offset
  Serial.println(millis());  
}
```

---

### ISSUE

I am working on a small embedded project and I want to use an Arduino Uno for realization.
I don't like the Arduino IDE and want to use Visual Studio Code instead.
I managed to get everything running so far. I can compile and upload the code to the Board to get some output on the serial monitor for example.
So far so good.

Now I want to dive deeper and set some register bits to set up a timer interrupt. This code below throws an error in VS Code during verfication, but not in Arduino IDE. I uploaded via Arduino IDE and the code runs as expected.
Does anyone know how to overcome this issue in VS Code?

I am a beginner, so please don't wonder about the structre and the actual content of the code. At the moment I am trying to figure out how to use header files correctly and how to set up a useful structure.

Thanks in advance!

**CODE Main.ino**

```
#include "init.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

int i = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  ;
}
```

**CODE init.h**

```
#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H

#include <Arduino.h>

#define PRESCALE_OFFSET 3035;


/*
Functions
*/
int function01(int a);

#endif
```

**CODE init.cpp**

```
#include "init.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

TCCR1A = 0; //WGM10 WGM11 normal mode for 16bit timer
TCCR1B = 0; //WGM12 WGM13 normal mode for 16bit timer
TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12); //prescaler set to 256
TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1); //enable interrupts on timer2 (16bit timer)

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect)        
{
  TCNT1 = PRESCALE_OFFSET; //let the timer start at offset
  Serial.println(millis());  
}

int function01(int a)
{
    a++;
  return a;
}
```

---

**ERROR**

```
[Starting] Verifying sketch 'Main.ino'
[Warning] Output path is not specified. Unable to reuse previously compiled files. Build will be slower. See README.
Konfiguration wird geladen...
Pakete werden initialisiert...
Boards werden vorbereitet...
Überprüfungsvorgang...
In file included 
from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,
from c:\program files (x86)\arduino\hardware\tools\avr\avr\include\avr\pgmspace.h:90,
from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:28,
from c:\Users\pelzk\OneDrive\3D Prints\04 Projekte\Hydroponic\Coding\hydroponics\init.h:4,
from c:\Users\pelzk\OneDrive\3D Prints\04 Projekte\Hydroponic\Coding\hydroponics\init.cpp:5:
init.cpp:8:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'volatile'
 TCCR1A = 0; //WGM10 WGM11 normal mode for 16bit timer
 ^
init.cpp:8:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:8:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'volatile'
 TCCR1B = 0; //WGM12 WGM13 normal mode for 16bit timer
 ^
init.cpp:9:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:9:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'volatile'
 TCCR1B |= (1<<CS12); //prescaler set to 256
 ^
init.cpp:10:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:10:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:11:1: error: expected unqualified-id before 'volatile'
 TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1); //enable interrupts on timer2 (16bit timer)
 ^
init.cpp:11:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
init.cpp:11:1: error: expected ')' before 'volatile'
exit status 1
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=1e6f5c3, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@28087]
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopping LoggerContext[name=1e6f5c3, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@28087]...
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=StatusLogger]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=ContextSelector]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 1 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=Loggers,name=]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering 2 MBeans: [org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile, org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=Appenders,name=Console]
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=1e6f5c3,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Arduino/lib/pde.jar!/log4j2.xml]...
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notified 2 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping 1 LoggerConfigs.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager C:\Users\pelzk\AppData\Local\Arduino15/logs/application.log
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down RollingFileManager C:\Users\pelzk\AppData\Local\Arduino15/logs/application.log
DEBUG StatusLogger All asynchronous threads have terminated
DEBUG StatusLogger RollingFileManager shutdown completed with status true
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down RollingFileManager C:\Users\pelzk\AppData\Local\Arduino15/logs/application.log, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender RollingFile stopped with status true
DEBUG StatusLogger Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false.false
DEBUG StatusLogger Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_ERR.false.false, all resources released: true
DEBUG StatusLogger Appender Console stopped with status true
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration stopped 2 remaining Appenders.
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 2 LoggerConfigs.
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped XmlConfiguration[location=jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Arduino/lib/pde.jar!/log4j2.xml] OK
DEBUG StatusLogger Stopped LoggerContext[name=1e6f5c3, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@28087] with status true
IntelliSense configuration already up to date. To manually rebuild your IntelliSense configuration run "Ctrl+Alt+I"
[Error] Verifying sketch 'Main.ino': Exit with code=1
```

Comment: Try putting those four assignments (TCCR1 to TIMSK1) inside a routine, and call it from `setup`. It's strange to see them treated as global variables; they aren't really.

Comment: Not sure how that works even in the Arduino IDE. It's not valid c or c++. You're assigning variables that don't have a type designator.

Comment: Not that this has anything to do with your problem, but you probably don't want the semicolon in `#define PRESCALE_OFFSET 3035;`  Also, like aMike said.

Comment: Arduino IDE 2.0 (Beta) is build on same components as Visual Studio Code